# After initiating the WP_Query object, all the post permalinks are showing the same page

Tags: wordpress, loops, permalinks, posts

I have initialized WP_Query object and using that object to show post information. But, when I go the permalink for any post, it showing the home page rather than that post page. Here is my index.php code:

```html
<?php
 $myWpQuery = new WP_Query(array( 'author_name' => 'me' ));
 if($myWpQuery->have_posts()){
  while ($myWpQuery->have_posts()) {
   $myWpQuery->the_post();
   ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br />
   <?php
  }
 }
?>
```

I have three post with the author name "me". When I am loading the home page (http://localhost/wordpress/) its showing the title of those three posts inside proper anchor tag. But when I am clicking on the title, It's taking me to the post page (http://localhost/wordpress/hello-world/). Problem is here. This post page is also showing those three title as home page. But I expected only the title of the post that I clicked on.

But when I am using the simple following code it's working properly.

```html
<?php
 if(have_posts()){
  while (have_posts()) {
   the_post();
   ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br />
   <?php
  }
 }
?>
```

What's happening after initializing the WP_Query object. Could anyone explain it please.

Comment: Your WP_Query loop looks ok, but what is the context? Is that all of your index.php file?

Comment: Yes, It's all I have in my index.php file. And just two file in my theme. index.php and style.css. I am learning, that's why it's simple. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Because you use `the_post()` in your query, you need to reset after to restore the global $post variable of the main query loop. The right way to do this when using `WP_Query()` is to call `wp_reset_postdata()` after your custom loop like this:

```php
<?php
$myWpQuery = new WP_Query(array( 'author_name' => 'me' ));

if($myWpQuery->have_posts()){

    while ($myWpQuery->have_posts()) {

        $myWpQuery->the_post();

        ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br />
        <?php

    }

  // Restore original Post Data
   wp_reset_postdata();

} else {

  // No posts found

}
```

I'm not sure if this is causing your problem, but it's definitely something to fix. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a data setup. Take a look at the example below (taken from wordpress.org), that how your query should look like:

```
<ul>
<?php
  global $post;
  $args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1 );
  $myposts = get_posts( $args );
  foreach( $myposts as $post ) :
    setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php
  endforeach; 
  wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</ul>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata - here look at Example 1
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99597/what-does-setup-postdata-post-do - information on what setup_postdata() function does

Without setting up postdata, your loop may store data from the previous iteration. The same would work with **new WP_Query** instead of get_posts().